# Can agora.io SDK detect and flag bad user behavior during live streams?

Tags: agora.io

Can agora.io detect user bad behavior?

For example, smoking, being naked, drug, blood, or other bad behavior detect issues. Can Agora detect it?

If your website is designed to be prohibited from this category how to catch the bad behavior user?

How do they detect it? Is there more information about it?